# How can I manipulate lists?

Tags: python, list

In the computer algebra system [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/), 
I need to multiply a list by 2.

I tried the code

```
sage: list = [1, 2, 3];
sage: 2 * list
```

which returns

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

How can I just multiply each element by two?

Comment: Are you talking about this sage? : http://sagemath.org

Comment: What does Sage have to do with Python?

Comment: Sage uses python as its scripting language. Only the extensions are implemented using C and other libraries, so all user interaction is through python. It's at the top of the site.

Comment: This problem was also recently [asked on ask.sagemath.org](http://ask.sagemath.org/question/982/how-to-multiply-vector-by-number).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to multiply each element by 2? That would be:

```
[2*i for i in List]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
import numpy

numpy.multiply(List, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or convert the list to a vector first:

```
a = vector([1,2,3])
2*a
```

which returns

```
(2, 4, 6)
```

Vectors can be used in matrix-multiplication, and have methods which might be useful such as ".dot_product".

Btw, it is probably not a good idea in Sage or Python to call your variable "list".

Answer (score 0):

You manipulate lists in Sage just how you would manipulate them in Python because Sage is based on Python.  So, read about Python lists and you will learn to do whatever you want with lists in Sage.  Here:

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html